# trigger pod restart on configmap change

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a configmap file defined as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-dashboard-cm-conf
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
{{ (tpl (.Files.Glob "conf/*").AsConfig . ) | indent 2 }}
```

As you can see above, it is taking up the content of the "conf" folder as a data.
Everything works fine, however the issue is observed when i am trying to implement "annotations" to trigger a "POD-restart" with the below lines in my "deployment file.

```
      annotations:
        checksum/config-map: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/dashboard-conf-map.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

The POD is not getting restarted, even when content of "conf" folder is changed && a "helm upgrade" is performed.

If i use a simple configmap with data defined as below, a change in parameter and "helm upgrade" does result in POD-restart

```
data:
  parameter1: testparam1
  parameter2: testparam2
```

I have the following question in here

1. Is there a way to perform checksum for the folder.
2. Is there a way get the output of linux-command like below in the configmap.

`find dashboard/conf/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; |md5sum`

3. Can we perform checksum for a non-YAML file.

```
      annotations:
        checksum: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/logback-spring.xml") . | sha256sum }}
```

I get the below error
Error: YAML parse error on chart-2/charts/dashboar/templates/conf1/logback-spring.xml: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead

4. Can we perform checksum on file one directory above the ".Template.BasePath", i tried below combination all of them result in error.

```
checksum/config: {{ include (print .BasePath "../conf/values1.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

checksum/config: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/../../conf/values1.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

checksum/config: {{ include (print .Template.BasePath "/../conf/values1.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
```

error calling include: template: no template "chart-2/charts/dashboard/templates../conf/values1.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"

error calling include: template: no template "chart-2/charts/dashboard/templates/../conf/values1.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"

error calling include: template: no template "chart-2/charts/dashboard/templates/../../conf/values1.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"

Answer (score 6):

The [`include` template function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) is a Helm extension that executes a named template, just like the standard `template` directive, but returns the template's content as a string.  It has nothing to do with reading files.

To read back files, you need to use the [top-level `.Files` object](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/).  That specifically comes with a caveat that it cannot read files inside the chart's `templates` directory; prefixing file names with `.Template.BasePath` will not work, and you need to move the included files somewhere else.

Let's say you do create a subdirectory `conf` inside your main chart directory:

```
Chart.yaml
values.yaml
conf/
  logback.xml
templates/
  configmap.yaml
```

Many of the functions you list here – `.Files.Get`, `.Files.Glob.AsConfig`, `tpl` – return strings, so you can combine them together.  For example, you can compute a checksum for the rendered content of the ConfigMap as:

```yaml
annotations:
  checksum/config-map: {{ (tpl (.Files.Glob "conf/*").AsConfig . ) | sha256sum }}
```

You could do it on a single non-YAML file if you wanted, too: `.Files.Get` returns a string, so

```
.Files.Get "conf/logback-spring.xml" | sha256sum
```

The root path for `.Files.Get` is the root of the chart.  You can retrieve any file *not* in the `templates` directory, but you can't reach outside the chart.

Comment: Thanks a ton David, just what i was looking for, the solution provided by you worked like a charm :)

Comment: Hi David, Is there any way I can refer to the file outside the chart for performing checksum.
I have actually chart-a and chart-b, chart-a includes all the configuration configmaps and chart-b is generic. chart-b currently holds the deployment.yaml and checksum to be configured for the configmap belongs to chart-a.

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a good way to do this; you might ask a separate SO question describing your setup.

Comment: Hi David, are you seeing any possibility for this (referring to the config map yaml files under different chart) ?.

Comment: @DavidMaze, same question as srinivas. I'm planning to access the configmap.yaml in my parent chart from my subchart, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with sub-chart.

```yaml
kind: <ResourceKind> # Deployment, StatefulSet, etc
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include ("mylibchart.configmap") . | sha256sum }}
```

Another option is https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

You can use regex to select the config based on this PR https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/pull/314